# Find the frequency of all words from a concatenated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have concatenated text column derived from three columns in a table. I need to have frequency of all single words from that concatenated column.

```
Column1       Column2   column3
This is       Test       1
This was      Test       two
```

What I need is concatenation of all three i.e. This is Test 1, This was Test two and then count of each word ie.

```
This - 2
is  - 1
was -1
Test - 2
1- 1
two - 1
```

Comment: Just curious.  Where do you land on punctuation and items like "he/she"  is that one word or two?   How about "New York", is that one proper noun or two words.  In other words, this seems like a slippery slope,

Answer (score 0):

You can use string_split and cross apply to achieve the required result. try the following:

**Code:**

```
declare @tab table (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(100))

insert into @tab
select 'This is', 'Test', '1'
union
select 'This was','Test','two'

select value, count(*) rec_count 
from @tab 
cross apply string_split((col1+' '+col2+' '+col3), ' ') 
group by value
```